# Proving series if it is convergent

Tags: calculus

I have a series below. i did test of divergence and it shows 0. next i proceed with the below comparision test using

Comparison test -> $$\frac{1}{{n}^{3/2}}$$ Since $\frac{3}{2} > 1$, it converge and by comparsion test the series converge as well. Are my working correct?

Series->$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n^2)+\cos(n^2)}{{n}^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Well, not quite. You can have $\sin(n^2)+\cos(n^2)>1$, so you need to do the comparison test with $\frac{2}{n^{3/2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\cos(n^2)+\sin(n^2) \le 2$, we have $$\frac{\cos(n^2)+\sin(n^2)}{n^{3/2}}\le \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}=2\bigg( \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\bigg)$$.

Comment: i think $\cos n^2+\sin n^2 \le \sqrt2 $  not 2

Comment: Since $\cos x \le 1 $ and $\sin x \le 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\cos x + \sin x \le 1 + 1 =2$.

Comment: That does not hold because $\cos(x)$ depends on $\sin(x)$.

Comment: You can have stronger bound than $2$, but $2$ still works as an upper bound.

Comment: Brad, what does not hold?

Comment: @TheSubstitute can you give me an $x$ for which $\sqrt{2} \lt \sin(x) + \cos(x) \leq 2$?

Comment: @TheSubstitute you could write $\sqrt2( \frac{1}{\sqrt2}sinn^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}cosn^2)$=$\sqrt2$sin($n^2$+pi/4)$\le$ $\sqrt2$

Comment: Brad, why would I want/need to do that?

Comment: @Brad that doesn't matter for this question though

Comment: I guess we are just arguing convention. I don't use "less than or equal to" unless equality is reached for some values. I would write "$\cos(n^2) + \sin(n^2) \lt 2$" rather than "$\cos(n^2) + \sin(n^2) \leq 2$".

Comment: @Brad, be careful. If you just don't know if  equality is reached, but *might*, less than or equal is right. Also if you don't care. Don't restrict yourself too much. So $\sqrt{2} \le 2 \le 1000$